# Oauth2 in Symfony 5 error : Key path "file:///var/oauth/private.key" does not exist or is not readable

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, private-key

I build a oauth2 server in a web application with Symfony 5 and oauth2 bundle trikoder/oauth2-bundle in order to  login  a user of an other client  site. I get this error when the client site activate the authorize request. I read the answers on Stackoverflow to this issue but they answered to a Laravel issue, not Symfony 5.
Here is the .env file :

###> trikoder/oauth2-bundle ###

## Fallback OAuth2 encryption key

## Please override this with a secure value: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/installation/#string-password

OAUTH2_STRING_PASSWORD=4YUuCt##################x2wsEdg

OAUTH2_ENCRYPTION_KEY=def#######################################################cbf

#### < trikoder/oauth2-bundle

Here is the config/packages/trikoder_oauth2.yaml file

```
trikoder_oauth2:

authorization_server:
    private_key: /var/oauth/private.key                     # Change this
    private_key_passphrase: null                            # Passphrase of the private key, if any

    encryption_key: '%env(string:OAUTH2_ENCRYPTION_KEY)%'   # (Optional) Change this
    encryption_key_type: "defuse"
    # How long the issued access token should be valid for.
        # The value should be a valid interval: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php#refsect1-dateinterval.construct-parameters
    access_token_ttl:     PT1H

        # How long the issued refresh token should be valid for.
        # The value should be a valid interval: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php#refsect1-dateinterval.construct-parameters
    refresh_token_ttl:    P1M

        # How long the issued auth code should be valid for.
        # The value should be a valid interval: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php#refsect1-dateinterval.construct-parameters
    auth_code_ttl:        PT10M



resource_server:
    public_key: /var/oauth/public.key                       # Change this

persistence:
    doctrine: null
```

The public.key and private.key are in the var/auth/ path.
The client  is created in the oauth2_client table with the two parameters identifier and secret.
Thanks a lot for your response !
Alain Jouve

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo in your config?

/var/**oauth**/private.key instead of /var/**auth**/private.key as you described?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The path is really var/oauth/, I

Comment: Wher is an errot in my message not in my sytem.

Comment: This error occurs if an user is identified in the server application. But if no user is logged, the index page of the server is rendered, not a loging form.

Comment: Im not sure about this, i would ned to run an example and debug that. But the error "file does not exist or is not readable" tends to be some issue with read permissions (if its really exists). Have you checked that properly?

Comment: The issue is solved:  the path was wrong in the trikoder_oauth2.yaml file : /var/oauth/ in place of var/oauth/ which is right.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the file owners of public.key and private.key, like this:

```
sudo chown -R www:data:www-data public.key private.key
```

And that should solve your problem, if not let me know and I'll help you.